# DataTables 1.10: Using saveState to remember filtering and order but need to update address URL to have shareable link for others

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I use `saveState: true` to keep the conditions for my DataTables when ordering columns or filtering results with a phrase. When I refresh the page, conditions remain thanks to the local storage.

[image]

This works great within the same browser, but imagine a quite common case when after you apply both ordering and filtering to your table, you would like to share this state with your friend by simply copying and pasting a long URL with query string so that when he / she opens it, the table looks exactly the same.

[There was a plugin that used to do this](https://github.com/jhyland87/DataTables-Keep-Conditions) but it's not maintained and after giving it a try, it does not work with `1.10` at all.

I wonder if it's possible to solve this by using just some native code and maybe `replaceState` to simply update URL when applicable?

This is my JS.

```
$(function () {
    let table = $('.table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        stateSave: true,
        stateSaveCallback: function (settings, data) {
            // save state
        },
        stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
            // read state and change url?
        },

        ajax: '{{ route('admin.api.dt.customer.index') }}',
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            targets: 2
        }],
        pageLength: {{ \App\Repositories\Sync\CustomerRepository::PER_PAGE_DATA_TABLES }},
    });
});
```

Based on this code the obvious issue is that the `ajax` URL is my hardcoded Laravel route. Simply passing query string does not work.

My Laravel route is simply: `http://iosportal.local/admin/api/customer` and it returns `JSON` shaped to suit DataTables.

[image]

Can somebody give my a hint how to approach this?

Comment: If you figure out how to build the key value used in localstorage so you can do `localStorage.getItem(key)` it shouldn't be too difficult to send that data to server to store it and build a custom url there that would know which config to load and merge that config with the plugin config before initalizing the plugin. I know this comment is oversimplified but I would be willing to help you work through this a bit if you get the storage key sorted out

Comment: Along that line of thinking...it might be as simple as figuring out what the key would be on a slightly different url and load the same data into other users  localStorage before initializing plugin with `stateSave: true,`  and let plugin pull that state from storage

Comment: KeepConditions works for me for v1.10, see [my review](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-save-and-restore-table-state-using-unique-url). There is also [deepLink](https://datatables.net/blog/2017-07-24) but it can't be compared to KeepConditions.

Comment: @MattKomarnicki - Did you get a chance to try the answer I posted here?

Answer (score 3):

I found storing the current state as base64 was easy and portable. You'll need to create some sort of UI for retrieving the state which could be anything, but at it's most primitive you can have a button:

```
<a id="get-state">Get State</a>
```

And do something like this:

```
$('#get-state').on('click', function() {
    var saved = btoa(JSON.stringify(table.state()));
    alert('state=' + saved);
})
```

Now append that as a query parameter to get your shareable url:

> https://example.com?state=eyJzZWFyY2giOnsic2VhcmNoIjoibWVvdyIsInNtYXJ0Ijp0cnVlLCJyZWdleCI6ZmFsc2UsImNhc2VJbnNlbnNpdGl2ZSI6dHJ1ZX19

To restore the state have something like this in your datatable options:

```
// use stateLoadParams() instead of stateLoadCallback() since the former
// is designed for exactly what you want — manipulating the loaded state
"stateLoadParams": function (settings, data) {
    // check the current url to see if we've got a state to restore
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    var state = url.searchParams.get("state");
    if (state) {
        // if so, try to base64 decode it and parse into object from a json
        try {
            state = JSON.parse(atob(state));
            // now iterate over the object properties and assign any that
            // exist to the current loaded state (skipping "time")
            for (var k in state) {
                if (state.hasOwnProperty(k) && k != 'time') {
                    data[k] = state[k];
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Note I'm skipping the "time" attribute here since it may invalidate your state expiry.

Answer (score 2):

@billynoah's `stateLoadParams` utilization should work for most of the scenarios, however `stateLoadParams` is being fired only when there is already some saved state in local storage - so when you are accessing given URL for the first time it will not work.

Much cleaner way how to achieve sharing through URL is to edit [stateSaveCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSaveCallback) and [stateLoadCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateLoadCallback) so they will not use local storage at all and will use url parameters instead.

This is all you need to add into respective datatable config. It also updates URL without need of reload on every state change (or state save to be more precise) and it works for multiple tables as well. The only requirement is that every table element has to have its own specific ID.

```js
stateSaveCallback: function (settings, data) {
    //encode current state to base64
    const state = btoa(JSON.stringify(data));
    //get query part of the url
    let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    //add encoded state into query part
    searchParams.set($(this).attr('id') + '_state', state);
    //form url with new query parameter
    const newRelativePathQuery = window.location.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString() + window.location.hash;
    //push new url into history object, this will change the current url without need of reload
    history.pushState(null, '', newRelativePathQuery);
},
stateLoadCallback: function (settings) {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    let state = url.searchParams.get($(this).attr('id') + '_state');

    //check the current url to see if we've got a state to restore
    if (!state) {
        return null;
    }

    //if we got the state, decode it and add current timestamp
    state = JSON.parse(atob(state));
    state['time'] = Date.now();

    return state;
}
```